# React Native Product Detail Page for each products

Tags: react-native, react-redux, shopping-cart

How to setup 1000 + products in React native .Also Do we need to Create Separate pages manually for each Product ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**FlatList**

A performant interface for rendering basic, flat lists, supporting the most handy features:

- Fully cross-platform.
- Optional horizontal mode.
- Configurable viewability callbacks.
- Header support.
- Footer support.
- Separator support.
- Pull to Refresh.
- Scroll loading.
- ScrollToIndex support.
- Multiple column support.

If you need section support, use .

Demo: https://snack.expo.dev/@g1sm0/flatlist-simple

Doc: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

*PERSONAL NOTE: DON'T FORGET THE KEY EXTRACT!*